# Textarea without right side scrolbar

Tags: javascript, html, css, scrollbar

Is it possible to use CSS on a `<textarea>` to remove the right side scrollbar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What have you tried so far? Can you paste the code you are currently using?
Try adding the following CSS rule for your Text area:

`overflow-y:hidden;`

Comment: This will only disable the vertical scrollbars but still allow horizontal scroll bars.

If you want to disable both, then use `overflow: hidden;`

Comment: This is the best answer to the question asked – it was specifically about right side scrollbar. Perhaps it needs to add that the CSS code does just that, removes the vertical scrollbar; it does not prevent the user from entering any amount of lines, but he cannot see those lines that don’t fit into the visible area.

Answer (score 2):

In general, this can be done with a `overflow: hidden;` style attribute.

```
<textarea style="width: 500px; height: 100px; overflow: hidden;"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can assign height value

```
textarea{height:150px; width:300px; overflow:hidden}​
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qhxW3/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following rule

```
overflow: hidden;
```